# How to return data that has a many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I had to change a one to many to a many to many relationship. With the former A user was assigned a companyId upon registering. The only documents they could return from the database was controlled with a where statement in my Web Api. Now that a User can be assigned many companies I need to change that where statement to do the same thing.

Error

```
Error   1   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TransparentEnergy.Models.Company>'    C:\Development\TransparentEnergy\TransparentEnergy\ControllersAPI\apiDocumentUserController.cs  31  33  TransparentEnergy
```

ApiController

```
   public IEnumerable<DocumentResult> Get()
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return context.Documents
                .Where(j => j.CompanyId == user.Companies)
          .ToResults();
        }

    }
```

Class

```
 public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; } 
}
```

Class

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager
            .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Update
Junction Table

```
 public class UserCompany
{
    [Key]
    public int UCompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
 }

 public class Company
  {
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public int UserCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserCompany UserCompany { get; set; }

   }

 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
   {
     public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
     {
        var userIdentity = await manager
            .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
     }
     public int UserCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserCompany UserCompany { get; set; }
   }
```

Controller

```
  public List<Document> GetDocuments()
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return context.Documents
                .Where(j => j.CompanyId == user.UserCompany.UCompanyId)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Error

> Non-static method requires a target.

Stacktrace

> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryGetFieldOrPropertyValue(MemberExpression me, Object instance, Object& memberValue)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryEvaluatePath(Expression expression, ConstantExpression& constantExpression)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at TransparentEnergy.ControllersAPI.apiDocumentUserController.GetDocuments() in c:\Development\TransparentEnergy\TransparentEnergy\ControllersAPI\apiDocumentUserController.cs:line 29
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the specifics about entity framework syntax, but if you have a many to many relationship between Users and Companies you need to create an associative table called something like "UserCompany".  This table would hold the primary keys of User and Company as foreign keys, then you could pull the UserCompany primary key to see which users are related to which companies.

Comment: It created one, UserCompanies. It has ApplicationUser_Id and Company_CompanyId. There is no primary key column for the table

Comment: I would go into the actual code of the model object that entity framework created for UserCompanies and add a primary key manually.  It shouldn't be too much work just to add a primary key integer attribute in the model for that object.

Comment: found some help on creating the key. thanks for you help